# Adding days to a date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am have a column of dates that I need to add a variable amount of days to.  So I don't think I can use the normal date_add (date, interval x day).

```
date          numOfDays
2001-01-01        5
2001-05-22        3
2002-03-04        2
...               ...
```

I'm basically looking for something like:

```
select date, numOfDays, (date + numOfDays) as newDate
from t1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`,
       `numOfDays`,
       (`date` + INTERVAL `numOfDays` DAY) AS `newDate`
  FROM `t1`;
```

Comment: @acesnap: No problemo. Incidentally, you already pretty much had this solution; why didn't you just try it?!

Comment: thought i need to use concat or something to string the parts together and that didn't work.

Comment: @acesnap: Nah, `CONCAT` works on strings, not language constructs and operators.